# Is it possible for a node and its children to have separate physics bodies?

Tags: sprite-kit, scenekit

I have a moving car, which is an empty node containing two `SCNodes`:

- the actual car node,
- car barrier - transparent capsule around the car, used for detecting objects that are near the car.

I would like to have the actual car to have a physics body used for collisions with objects and one for the parent (the empty node), on which I could use forces for movement.

I am not sure if the child (actual car) should have body type set to dynamic/kinematic or static because it itself does not have forces applied to it, but its parent does. Right now both physics bodies are dynamic, because it is moving, due to the forces applied to its parent. I am just checking it this is correct.

With setting those two physics bodies I get really weird car (actual car representation) behavior. The car is floating in air and moving by itself, without any forces applied. Meanwhile the empty parent is in the correct position and moving like instructed.

I am not sure if I shouldn't create physics bodies for children of a parent who already has a physics body or I am setting something incorrectly.

I can add some code but I don't think it would be useful because I am just creating those physics bodies and setting category, collision and contact bit masks.

Comment: you need to turn off collision on the inner car,  the mask by default is all on, so it gets "pushed" outside due to 2 mass bodies not allowing to occupy the same space at the same time  'car.collisionBitMask = 0'  Also, the parent body needs to have car's category turned off